# Makefile: no rule to make target '*.o', needed by '*'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I got the following error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `stretchy_buffer.o', needed by `tsh'.  Stop
```

Trying to make this makefile

```
SRCS = stretchy_buffer.c def.c tsh_builtin_commands.c tsh_jobs.c tsh_main.c tsh_routines.c tsh_signals.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

tsh: $(OBJS)
    gcc -Wall -g -o tsh $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add following rule in your makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

%.o:%.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

In your existing makefile, there is no rule specified for obtaining *.o from *.c files and, hence, the error is reported.

Comment: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html has details about the use of implicit (default) compilation rule when Makefile does not contain the compilation rule.

Comment: Do you need the `gcc` line? If we can assume that `CC=gcc`

Comment: @jayant, you are correct. If we declare CC=gcc then $(CC) can be used instead of directly using gcc. Since, the original makefile directly used 'gcc', I maintained it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @cm161 Thank you - such a simple thing.  I did not fully understand the pattern matching technique being applied at the time.  Makefile's documentation is great for a few source files, but most examples that use pattern matching are overly confusing!  CMake, make this bad stuff go away!

Comment: what are NASM flags if nasm is used what should I use for CFLAGS?