# no rule to make target needed by x.o NASM and producing .o file as output. What mean by tthis error -- How to correct it

Tags: c, makefile, binary, operating-system, nasm

I am getting error

```
No rule to make target 'kernel-entry.asm', needed by 'kernel-entry.o'.  Stop.
```

Can .asm file containing assembly instructions get converted to .o file? I did not no

from this page

[Makefile: no rule to make target '*.o', needed by '*'. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315155/makefile-no-rule-to-make-target-o-needed-by-stop)

its say I have to include $(CFLAGS)

After making chages My make file looks like this

```
# $@ = target file
# $< = first dependency
# $^ = all dependencies

# First rule is the one executed when no parameters are fed to the Makefile

CFLAGS= -Wall -g
all: run

kernel.bin: kernel-entry.o kernel.o
    ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

kernel-entry.o: kernel-entry.asm
    nasm $(CFLAGS) $< -f elf -o $@

kernel.o: kernel.c
    gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

mbr.bin: mbr.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

os-image.bin: mbr.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > $@
```

But the error  `No rule to make target 'kernel-entry.asm', needed by 'kernel-entry.o'.  Stop.` did not go away. What I am doing wrong?

How to correct the error. Thanks for help

**Update**

Yes my kernel-entry file was .c I made it `.asm` and removed -CFLAGS because I was getting invalid NASM flags on CFLAGES Now I am getting this error

```
 warning: overriding recipe for target 'abc.bin'
Makefile:4: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'abc.bin'
nasm kernel-entry.asm -f elf -o kernel-entry.bin
kernel-entry.asm:2: error: invalid directive line
make: *** [Makefile:11: kernel-entry.bin] Error 1
```

are `-f elf -o` in above line are directives? What they are used for. is above error saying that `-f elf -o` are invalid. what above even means?

This is my make file thats generating error after **Update** above

```
all: run 

abc.bin:abc.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@


kernel.bin: kernel-entry.bin kernel.o
    ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

kernel-entry.bin: kernel-entry.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@


kernel.o: kernel.c
    gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@


abc.bin: abc.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@    


mbr.bin: mbr.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

os-image.bin: abc.bin mbr.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > $@

run: os-image.bin
    qemu-system-i386 -fda $<

clean:
    $(RM) *.bin *.o *.dis
```

Comment: Do you have a `kernel-entry.asm` file? Make would like to compile it (using nasm), but cannot find it.

Comment: @dratenik Yes the name was .c I changed it to .asm. Then I got error of CFLAGS that they are wrong directives with NASM I THINK THAT S the error I was getting So I removed CFLAGS Now I am getting NASM error `Makefile:19: warning: overriding recipe for target 'abc.bin'
Makefile:4: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'abc.bin'
nasm kernel-entry.asm -f elf -o kernel-entry.bin
kernel-entry.asm:2: error: invalid directive line
make: *** [Makefile:11: kernel-entry.bin] Error 1`

Comment: You have two rules for abc.bin doing the same thing. Harmless and easily fixable (delete one). And your kernel-entry.asm contains something that's not valid assembly.

Comment: @dratenik yes u are correct. I fixed it. But now I need x86-64 gcc elf cross compiler. How to install it on ubuntu 21? do u any thing about it

Comment: [gcc-multilib?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855945/what-exactly-does-gcc-multilib-mean-on-ubuntu) [see also](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/gcc-multilib)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in line `13` of your `Makefile` you have:

```
kernel-entry.o: kernel-entry.asm
    nasm $(CFLAGS) $< -f elf -o $@
```

which states how to create (by assembling it with `nasm`) `kernel-entry.o` from `kernel-entry.asm`.  By the way, `kernel-entry.o` is needed to create `kernel.bin` above in your makefile.  But as you don't have `kernel-entry.asm`, the `make` utility complains about not being able to create `kernel-entry.o` because there's no existing source file to generate it (and there is no rule to generate file `kernel-entry.asm`, in case it could be built automatically).

You lack a source file (an assembler file called `kernel-entry.asm`) and you have no `kernel-entry.o` either, so you cannot solve the problem without providing it.

#### Edit

You say you made an `kernel-entry.asm` file from your `kernel-entry.c` file (I cannot guess the reason to do that, but anyway it is not important here) but at some point you lost your `kernel-entry.asm` file.  This is what `make` is telling you... that it doesn't find the source file (neither `kernel-entry.asm` nor `kernel-entry.c`, to generate `kernel-entry.o` needed to link the final program)  You can use any, or even both rules, to generate the `.asm` file from the `.c` one, and then provide the C source code.

Anyway, apart of this... the default rule (the first one in your makefile, for target `all`) shows that it depends on target `run`, which is not defined anywhere, so if you run just:

```
make
```

you will get a similar message about no rule for target `run`.  This is because you say `all` depends on `run`, and `run` depends on nothing, so `make` assumes `run` (or `kernel-entry.asm`) must be provided by the user, or the build will fail.

Another important thing is that if you build a rule for compiling (using `gcc` or whatever) and you declare a set of common options for compiling `.c` files, there's nothing special in variable `CFLAGS` that makes it to be used by the compiler, so you have to rewrite all rules' commands in which you compile C code to read as the one below:

```
kernel.o: kernel.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -m32 -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@
```

or the `-Wall` and `-g` options will never be used on compiling (`CFLAGS` are, by convention, compiling flags, not assembling, so use instead `ASFLAGS` for assembling, as compiler flags probably will not be well received by `nasm`)

Comment: My last error was which I mentioned in my last one or two comments was I did not have cross compiler. I need that cross compiler gcc and also cross something for ld.

Comment: Please take a look at this and then I am sure u will know what and why I am doing/done which cause the error. Can u please take a look. This is i found after long time to finally get into my os and kernel development interest.This is kind my first challenge for me to face. I been familiar with real linux kernal code by reading linux device driver book and understanding code for e1000e and realtek drivers for network and pci hardware devices.And lots of reading. So can u please get me through this little bit. Take a look at the link Thanks https://dev.to/frosnerd/writing-my-own-boot-loader-3mld

Comment: `kernel-entry.bin: kernel-entry.asm nasm $< -f elf -o $@... u say u made a kernel-entry.asm from kernel-entry.c` I may have made a mistake in saying this. I dont have kernal-entry.c` or i only had it in ther very beginning but I change the extension to .asm because it contained assembly language code. Never contained c language code.initialally only I saved it with wrong extension which was .c but I should have saved to with .asm extension it was a mistake. Dont distract by that because I corrected the extension to .Asm file see comment.Consider this comment as my first comment below ur answer